# How to set a custom picture background on Ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, desktop-background

Simple question, but I could not manage to do it:

I found in Settings->Background to change the background. However, I found not way to select a picture from a file location.

- From file browser, there is no option to set as background an image
- From the Gallery, there is no option to set as background an image
- From Settings->background, there is no option to browse for a file.

---

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps you mean UBports? Ubuntu Touch isn't supported anymore I'm afraid. You would probably be better off asking at UBports' own forum.

Comment: Canonical would terminate support due to lack of market interest on 5 April 2017. A loooong time ago.

Comment: Oh! I was not aware of this "nomenclature" difference. Thank you

Comment: The UBports community took over support for Ubuntu Touch after canonical dropped it. So the OS is still called Ubuntu Touch and is still very much alive! :-)

Comment: By the way, which version of Ubuntu is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently (2021-10-03) a small UI bug there.

Head for system settings -> background. Go to the bottom of the page and press the "custom" button.

Then swipe up the page a bit. Another set of buttons shows up that allows picking an image.